# Digital output (FET) behavior

Tags: mosfet

Roboteq motor controllers (e.g. [SDC2160](https://www.roboteq.com/products/products-brushed-dc-motor-controllers/sdc2160-detail)) have several open drain digital outputs. We use them to switch a single segment of 24V LED strip, drawing about 17mA. At first everything seemed to work just fine, then we noticed that when switched off the LEDs have a faint glow. They had ~13V on them.

After long back-and-forth with manufacturer we reached their engineering team. They tested with 120 Ohm resistor and said that everything works fine and our problem is that *the load is too small, not enough for MOSFET to close*. We did more tests:

- Increased the length of LED strip to draw about 500 mA. Still faint glow in OFF state and same 13V across;
- Tested with 100 Ohm resistor. The voltage on resistor dropped to 30mV, confirming their test;
- Added 10k resistor in parallel to LED strip. The voltage now about 400mV and NO GLOW;

There are only few details in the datasheet: 1A maximum current, 1.5Ohm open resistance.

Now, I always thought that with FET gate shorted to ground it should be fully closed no matter what load is connected to it. My guess is that the firmware sets MCU control pin to + to open DOUT and sets it floating (instead of GND) to put DOUT into high impedance state. Floating gate might explain why FET does not close completely. If that is so, than firmware fix should be trivial.

Does this make any sense, or should we add that 10k resistor and live with absolutely unnecessary extra drain on the battery?

Comment: Are you using the FET properly as a low-side switch to *power* the LED, or are you trying to use the FET to *short out* the LED and drop the supply voltage across a current limit resistor alone?  It's also vaguely possible you've zapped the FET gate oxide and they are now always somewhat on.

Comment: LEDs will glow (dimly) with mere microamps : and coincidentally the leakage current of FETs can be ... mere microamps. 10 kilohms will only waste 2.4mA and take care of the problem. (47K or 100K may be acceptable and waste less). Put a DMM on mA range in series with the LEDs...

Comment: @ChrisStratton the LED _strip_ is connected between +24V supply voltage and open drain DOUT pin. We tested this on several brand new controllers with the same result.

Comment: Those two digital outputs - can you open the case and determine which FETs it is using?  Could be that it doesn't "fully open" unless \$V_{GS}\$ is < 0v.

Comment: Sounds like the FET is either leaky, under-driven (cutoff), or has a drain pull (up/down) resistor installed.

Comment: @rdtsc The FETs are in SO-8 package marked 1NV04DP. Seems to be [this one](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/vns1nv04dp-e.pdf). Is that "IDSS = 75 uA" the culprit?

Comment: @BrianDrummond I still don't understand why resistor works. 10k should be so much higher than LEDs as to not make any difference

Comment: @rdtsc  Oh, and there are 10k pulldowns on the gates, so my theory about floating gates was wrong.

Comment: LEDs go very high impedance if there isn't enough forward voltage across them to make them conduct. They are settling at 13V forward voltage at which they conduct a few uA and glow very dim. If that few uA is 13uA then they are 1 Megohm at that point. Indeed that Idss= 30 or 75 uA is the problem. See how easy it is when you post the datasheet?

Comment: @BrianDrummond unfortunately I had to invalidate the warranty on $250 device to do that. Nevertheless, do you want to make that an answer?

Comment: Please don't use water valve open and closed terminology here. For an electronic device, open means deactivated and closed means activated.

Comment: @Andyaka Good point. I'll try to keep this in mind for the future. Not sure if I have to change this post since Roboteq engineers used this (apparently reversed) terminology in our communications with them.

Answer (score 0):

Note: The credit for this answer should go to @BrianDrummond, who provided an explanation in the comments.

So, it turns out that LEDs indeed can start glowing with merely microampere current. In fact, while testing them with various resistors in series I accidentally connected +24V to LED strip by touching battery with one hand and holding LED in the other. That was enough for entire 1A strip to glow.

The MOSFET 1NV04DP used in the digital output has leakage current 75uA @ 24V. More than enough for LEDs to light up.

Our solution to this problem was to add 47k resistors in parallel to each output.